# Python return a value from my function

Tags: python, list, function, return-value

I am currently trying to figure out how to extract the list of numbers created by this function.

```
def getInput():
    numlist = []
    while True:
        z = float(input("Enter a number (-9999 to quit): "))
        if z == -9999:
            print(numlist)
            return numlist
        else:
            numlist.append(z)
            print(numlist)


getInput()
```

Right now the print commands are just for me to confirm that I'm adding numbers to the list, but when the user quits, I need to be able to use new numlist in other functions (I'm going to find the averages of these numbers), and when I try to print the numlist after the function is done, I get an error, which leads me to believe the numlist is disappearing. Could I have some help please?

Comment: Thanks everyone, simpler than I thought haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not capturing the numlist being returned.

```
def getInput():
    numlist = []
    while True:
        z = float(input("Enter a number (-9999 to quit): "))
        if z == -9999:
            print(numlist)
            return numlist
        else:
            numlist.append(z)
            print(numlist)


numlist = getInput()
#do processing here
```

Comment: Thank you! Simpler than I thought haha

Answer (score 0):

Your function uses `return` to return the list object to the caller. You'd store that return value of the function in a new name:

```
result = getInput()
```

Now `result` will be a reference to the same list you built in the function.

You can give it any name you like; it can even be the same name as what was used in the function, but because this name isn't part of the function namespace, that name is entirely separate from the one in the function.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is essentially that any data acquired during a function call is put on the stack, and at the end of the function the stack is cleared. so as mentioned above, result = getInput() would do. or you could pass in a variable to the function as an argument and use that.